# How to setup Nginx server for angular and django

Tags: django, angular, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a web application to my server. I have put the html files in one folder and I have a django server running on the same server. I am using nginx to set up reverse proxy for the backend but for some reason I'm not able to route to backend urls.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com example.com;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html;

        # Let's Encrypt parameters
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ = index.html;
    }
        location /api {
          proxy_pass         http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
          proxy_redirect     off;

          proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
}
```

In the first block..I'm setting fallbacks to index.html because it is an angular app.
The angular app runs fine.

But I'm not able to access the routes of the reverse proxy server, whenever I hit a route with **/api/something** it takes me back to the angular app i.e index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple, I had to modify the path block like this

```
location ~^/(admin|api) {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
 }
```